# What does 'define formally' mean?

Tags: set, logic, sml, smlnj

I am taking a logic and functional programming course (with programming in SML) and as part of our first assignment the following question is asked

*"... You need to define an (abstract) type called 'a set
Documentation:  Describe formally how finite sets will be represented as lists, stating a representational invariant property. ..."*

Can anyone explain **what does "describe formally" means** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your textbook and class notes to see how "formal description" is used for other type, and then follow that example.

Answer (score 1):

Describe formally in mathematics usually means bounding things with mathematical expressions, and using standard notation and terminology where necessary.  In logic, you generally will use `implies` and `therefore` instead of more colloquial terms.  Wikipedia has an [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalism_%28mathematics%29)